# How to squash dirty commits from multiple branches

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

This is my current status in a Git project:

[image: Current Git status]

After I finished my job in dev branch, I tried to merge multiple commits several times but it seemed not to work properly. I tried `merge` and `rebase -i` but it produced dirty commits and branches. I want to squash `9fd5653f231` to current HEAD. I would appreciate anyone's help to get me through this.

Comment: You don't have a Dev branch, and all of your commits are already in master. What do you want to squash?

Comment: After I merged those commits, I deleted Dev branch. Commits from 9f5653 to current HEAD are useless commit due to merge conflict. So I just want to clean it to a single commit...

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your branch with `git rebase -i HEAD~8` (the last 8 commits you want to "hide"). Squash commits by replacing `pick` by `squash` on each unwanted commit line in the text editor.